# Negative cell in Li-ion battery pack

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion

I have a 6 cell Li-ion battery pack (from a knock-off dyson v6 vacuum battery) which is no longer taking charge.

The voltage across the whole pack is 3V. I have opened the pack and measured the voltage across each of the cells (PROS18650P1 3.6V 20G28 2Y). Cells 1-3 have ~4V across them, as does cells 5,6. Cell 4 however reads as -17V!

How can a Li-ion cell measure -17V across it? Is this possibly due to a fault/short in the BMS? Alternatively, is it possible the 4th cell is open circuit and therefore the voltage appears to be -17V because its actually measuring around through the board? Is there an easy way to test this without separating the cells?

Update: I have attached several photos showing the measured voltages across various cells.

Complete battery pack 2.9V:
[image: Whole battery pack]

Cell 6 3.9V:
[image]

Cell 5-6 7.8V:
[image]

Cell 4-6 -9.1V:
[image]

Cell 4 -16.9V:
[image]

Comment: I would desolder one of the terminals, however I don't have a safe place to do this at the moment

Comment: -11V or -17V sounds totally impossible for common li-po, I don't think they can safely have so much voltage difference across one battery and not swell or catch fire. What's the input voltage of BMS/charger?

Comment: Yeah I'm super confused I've never seen something like it. 26V from the charger, 3v total across the 6 cells in series

Comment: Is it possible battery is open circuit and therefore the voltage appears to be -17V because its actually measuring around through the board? Is there an easy way to test this without separating the cells?

Comment: That is a possibility. Each cell appears to be individually monitored by the charging circuit, presumably for balancing, so it's quite feasible that there could be some path back through them.

Comment: I've added photos, photos are at odd angles as I unfortunately don't have 3 hands or spring hook probes

Comment: Just had a similar thing  (also on a knock-off Dyson v6 battery pack).  3rd cell counting from ground measures (in circuit) -13.5v.   Negative of cell 1 to negative of cell 3 measures 7.6v, positive of cell 3 to positive of cell 6 is 11.4v, so I figure I'm missing about a cell's worth of voltage.  Battery pack gives 5 and a half blue flashes, just for the record.

Comment: Why is this closed as off-topic? It is not a repair question, it is a theory question of how this phenomenon is possible

Answer (score 1):

If what you report is correct, it means that a) there is a load across the Li-ion battery and b) cell #4 is open. That would be due to a bad cell, not to the BMS. Though not impossible, an open cell is not commonly seen.

However, it is possible that the information you gave us may be incorrect, that when you though you were measuring cell # 4 you were actually measuring the entire voltage of the Li-ion battery pack. Please post pictures, such as showing where you are measuring cell #4.

Comment: I'll post some photos tonight or tomorrow

Comment: I have attached some photos to the question, hopefully they will be sufficient to show what I observed. If you need any other measurements let me know.
I am assuming the pack is now a dud and am purely curious as to what happened. I usually live in the land of firmware so this is somewhat an intriguing mystery to me

Comment: +1 on open cell. This is the only logical explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I've dismantled several of these packs, both OEM and 3rd party, and never come across anything like this. I suggest that you are not measuring across a single cell. Since I presume you will not be trying to use it again so the best you can do is to split the pack into separate cells. You can discard any that won't charge and use the rest in LED torches and similar applications; that's what I do. Note that the cells are not soldered to the connecting straps but spot welded. These straps can be peeled off with a pair of pliers. Also note that the individual cells are not protected, so you will need to charge them on a proper LiPo charger

Comment: Yeah I was going to desolder the negative terminal (which is soldered) not the individual cells which are welded. I am definitely measuring across the cells. The total voltage across the pack is 3v

Comment: Please see photos attached, as indicated in my original post I definitely measured across the cells as indicated. If you have any further ideas of why this occurred feel free to update your answer, or if you have any other requests of tests you would like conducted to provide context post a comment under the question